# magento get configurable product's added simple product image in mini cart

Tags: magento

I'd like to get a configurable product's simple product images in a sidebar mini cart.

magento get configurable product's added simple product image in mini cart

Answer (score 4):

```
admin->system->config->sales->checkout->Shopping Cart
```

There you can find the settings